# Writing in List using switch c#

Tags: c#, list, switch-statement, case, store

I wanted to insert data from textbox to list.
But whenever I am trying to gather to count the number of rows no rows are created. or no data are stored in the list

Here is the sample of the code.

```cs
foreach (classfile row in list)
{
      switch (row.fld_ID)
      {
          #region Q1
          case 1:
              row.fld_Answer = QuestionTextBox1.Text.ToUpper().Trim();
              break;
          #endregion

          #region Q2
          case 2:
              row.fld_Answer = QuestionTextBox2.Text.ToUpper().Trim();
        }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown where items are being added.

Comment: Hi could you explain it to me? I am assuming that once it go to case 1: answer is already stored in first row of fld_Answer.

Comment: There already needs to be items in the list for the `switch` to be hit. Otherwise the `foreach` will exit immediately.

Comment: Oh you mean there must be an initial data in the list for it to work?

Comment: Yes, `foreach` iterates over items in a list, it is not used to insert items.

Comment: [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) is exactlly what it's english counter part is. 
"For each childs, you have to pay.." -"But I have no child!" -"Oh ok. Have a nice day.". 
For each is an enumeration. 
The list cannot be modify by the enumeration. No matter how many time you count those childs their number wont change. 
And Naming all of them wont create new a one. If you try to add a new item in a list your are enumerating, you will just get an error. "Wait a sec every time you count my childs, one of them disappear!"

Comment: Ohhhh i got it, do you have a suggestion on how can I insert data in list without the need of initial data? Because I am planning to put this on database by creating the list as XML

Comment: You still can modify the property of the element in the list. You can rename on of them, change is age, but You won't be able to delete/add to the list it self.

Comment: `var myData= new List<Foo>(); ` Here we have an empty list. `myData.Add(new Foo());` will add data to an empty list.

Comment: Ohhh i got this, thank you so much for helping!

Comment: You issue is a bit unclear, So I can only explain the basics without addressing your real question. I will recommend reading [ask] and create an [mre] with a simple bogus class. Explaining in sentence what you are really trying, and the step it should take. What is well explain is well conceive and the code flow with ease.